# Time series analysis, moving-average model, ARMA model

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, average, time-series

I'm reading documents about time series analysis, including [Autoregressive–moving-average model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model), [Moving average model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model), [Wold's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_theorem), etc.

> The notation MA(q) refers to the moving average model of order q:
>
> $$X_t = \mu + \varepsilon_t + \theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-1} + \cdots + \theta_q \varepsilon_{t-q} \qquad (*)$$
>
> where μ is the mean of the series, the $θ_1$, ..., $θ_q$ are the parameters of the model and the $ε_t$, $ε_{t−1}$,..., $ε_{t−q}$ are white noise error terms.

---

1) **I would understand if we would want to express $X_t$ as a linear combination of past values** $X_{t-1}$, $X_{t-2}$, $X_{t-3}$, etc. i.e. :

$$X_t = a_1 X_{t-1} + a_2 X_{t-2} + ... + a_q X_{t-q} + \epsilon_t$$

and **if we would want to find optimal values for $(a_i)_{i \leq q}$.**

This would make sense to me (by the way, does this approach exist, what's its name?).

---

2) But here I don't understand **why** we try to express $X_t$ in terms of past values of something which is *totally uncontrolled* and *has nothing to do with* $(X_t)$ : $\epsilon_t$, i.e. some random white noise!

**Why do we do this in the [moving average model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model)?**
(By the way, **how are exactly defined the $\epsilon_t$** ?)

Comment: Have you read the wiki article (your first link)?

Comment: @d.k.o. yes, but I don't see why we try to express our signal $X_t$ in terms of something we don't know : random noise $\epsilon_t$.

Comment: Why not? It is still possible to estimate $\theta$-s from data...

Comment: @d.k.o. Are $\epsilon_t$ errors terms of previous estimations in the past (if so, even if I would understand the global idea, how are they defined exactly? No definition about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model)) ?  In [Wold's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_theorem) are the $\epsilon_t$ just random white noise (if so, the $\Theta$ will vary from one execution of the algorithm to the other!) or are they also error terms of previous estimations?